# Index Rebuild online

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

I have a query in SQL Server 2012. During online index rebuild operation, what happens if I run a SQL query to read/write data to/from a particular table 'X' which co-incidentally may be undergoing the rebuild operation? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... while a clustered index is being rebuilt by one user, that user
>   and others can continue to update and query the underlying data.

**Ref**: [Perform Index Operations Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177442.aspx)

This obviously also applies to online rebuilds of non-clustered indexes.

[Guidelines for Online Index Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190981.aspx)

**Also**, online index rebuilds are much slower than offline ones, and use more transaction log space.

During an online index rebuild, the build phase takes **`IS`** (Intent Shared) and **`S`** (Shared) locks to ensure that other processes do not acquire any exclusive locks on the object while the index is being rebuilt. During the final phase, a schema modification **`Sch-M`** lock is taken. This lock blocks all other concurrent access to the table, but it is only held for a ***very short period of time*** while the old index is dropped and the metadata updated.